# Why does pygame.mixer.Sound().play() return None?

Tags: python, pygame

According to the [`pygame` documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play), `pygame.mixer.Sound().play()` should return a `Channel` object. It actually does.

**But sometimes**, it seems to return `None` because *the very next line*, I get this error:

```
NoneType has no attribute set_volume
```

when I try to type

```
channel = music.play(-1)
channel.set_volume(0.5)
```

---

Of course the error can happen because the sound is very short, but the error can't come from there (Is 5'38" shorter than the time `python` needs to shift from one line to the next?)

I also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> all the code to see if I typed somewhere `channel = None` (because I use multiple threads) - Nothing.

Does anybody had the same problem? Is that a `pygame` bug?

I use `python 3.8.2`, `pygame 2.0.1` and Windows.

---

Currently I bypass the error rather than fix it like that:

```
channel = None
while channel is None:
    channel = music.play()
channel.set_volume(0.5)
```

But... it doesn't seem to help very much: the game freezes, because `pygame` constantly returns None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sound.play()` returns `None` if it can't find a channel to play the sound on, so you have to check the return value. Using the `while` loop is obviously a bad idea.

Note that you can either set the volumne of not only an entire `Channel`, but also on a  `Sound` object, too. So you could set the volume of your `music` sound before trying to play it:

```
music.set_volume(0.5)
music.play()
```

If you want to make sure that `Sound` is played, you should get a `Channel` before and use that `Channel` to play that `Sound`, something like this:

```
# at the start of your game
# ensure there's always one channel that is never picked automatically
pygame.mixer.set_reserved(1)

...

# create your Sound and set the volume
music = pygame.mixer.Sound(...)
music.set_volume(0.5)
music.play()

# get a channel to play the sound
channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel(True) # should always find a channel
channel.play(music)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! Knowing this, it is obvious that the error came from there: the error was happening *randomly*, so it wasn't the program fault...

Comment: Well, one problem is that the documentation of the mixer module is ... not good, sometimes even just wrong.

Comment: And how do you play a sound repeatedly?

Comment: Obviously `channel.play(music, -1)`

Comment: Yes. Note that when you want to play background music, there's another module for that: `pygame.mixer.music`.