# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_busy'

Tags: python

I'm using pygame to play some sounds, I have the code

```
global PU1Sound
PU1Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("PU1.mp3")
```

and later using

```
PU1S = PU1Sound.play()
while PU1S.get_busy() == True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
PU1Sound.stop
```

and this works fine, playing the sound and waiting for it to play.
but later in the code I use

```
SCS = SCSound.play()
while SCS.get_busy() == True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
SCSound.stop
```

but for some reason this dose not work and instead results in the following error

**while SCS.get_busy() == True:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_busy'**

But if I put the code that is causing an error below the the code that isn't, it works like it should, but nothing about the placement should be causing it to cause a error.

so this works

```
def VideoD():
     PU1S = PU1Sound.play()
     while PU1S.get_busy() == True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
     PU1Sound.stop
     SVS = ScanVSound.play()
     while SVS.get_busy() == True:
         time.sleep(0.01)
     ScanVSound.stop
>     SCS = SCSound.play()
>     while SCS.get_busy() == True:
>         time.sleep(0.01)
>     SCSound.stop
>     PU2S = PU2Sound.play()
>     while PU2S.get_busy() == True:
>         time.sleep(0.1)
>     PU2Sound.stop
>     IPCS = IPCSound.play()
>     while IPCS.get_busy() == True:
>          time.sleep(0.1)
>     IPCSound.stop

    global username
    global TimeWaiting
    global c
    clear()
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    face1_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("facetest1.jpg")
    face1_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face1_image)[0]


    known_face_encodings = [
        face1_face_encoding,
    ]
    known_face_names = [
        username
    ]


    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []
    face_names = []
    process_this_frame = True
    scanThread.start()
    while True:
        ret, Frame = video_capture.read()
        small_frame = cv2.resize(Frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
        if process_this_frame:
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
            face_names = []
            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                name = "Unknown"
                face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
                if matches[best_match_index]:
                    name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
                    if TimeWaiting == False:
                        GrantedD()

                face_names.append(name)

        process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            cv2.rectangle(Frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            cv2.rectangle(Frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(Frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        Frame = cv2.resize(Frame, (300,250))
        cv2.imshow('Video', Frame)
        cv2.moveWindow('Video', 40,30)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Video', 300,250)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or (c <= 0):
            process_this_frame = False
            video_capture.release()
            title()
```

but this dose not work

```
def VideoD():
    PU1S = PU1Sound.play()
    while PU1S.get_busy() == True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    PU1Sound.stop
    SVS = ScanVSound.play()
    while SVS.get_busy() == True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    ScanVSound.stop
    global username
    global TimeWaiting
    global c
    clear()
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    face1_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("facetest1.jpg")
    face1_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face1_image)[0]


    known_face_encodings = [
        face1_face_encoding,
    ]
    known_face_names = [
        username
    ]


    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []
    face_names = []
    process_this_frame = True
    scanThread.start()
    while True:
        ret, Frame = video_capture.read()
        small_frame = cv2.resize(Frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
        if process_this_frame:
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
            face_names = []
            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                name = "Unknown"
                face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
                if matches[best_match_index]:
                    name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
                    if TimeWaiting == False:
                        GrantedD()

                face_names.append(name)

        process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            cv2.rectangle(Frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            cv2.rectangle(Frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(Frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        Frame = cv2.resize(Frame, (300,250))
        cv2.imshow('Video', Frame)
        cv2.moveWindow('Video', 40,30)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Video', 300,250)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') or (c <= 0):
            process_this_frame = False
            video_capture.release()
            

> SCS = SCSound.play()
>             while SCS.get_busy() == True:
>                 time.sleep(0.01)
>             SCSound.stop
>             PU2S = PU2Sound.play()
>             while PU2S.get_busy() == True:
>                 time.sleep(0.1)
>             PU2Sound.stop
>             IPCS = IPCSound.play()
>             while IPCS.get_busy() == True:
>                 time.sleep(0.1)
>             IPCSound.stop

            title()
```

Comment: Off-topic, but the `global ...` are all unnecessary.

Comment: the global was an attempt to fix the error, incase its caused by not finding the mp3 file, however this was not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only instance of `NoneType` is `None`, so your `SCS` being `None` is triggering the exception. You expected `SCSound.play()` to return a channel but it returned `None` instead because it [couldn't find a channel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408171/why-does-pygame-mixer-sound-play-returns-none)

Comment: the default amount of channels is 8, I am only using up to six, and only one channel is ever being played at a time before stopping and becoming an empty channel again, so this is not the problem, also if I put the code causing an error just below where I am using     `PU1S = PU1Sound.play()
    while PU1S.get_busy() == True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    PU1Sound.stop
    SVS = ScanVSound.play()
    while SVS.get_busy() == True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    ScanVSound.stop`                                                                                   then it dose not cause an error.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by the error showing up in one case or not the other, could you clarify these cases in your post?

Comment: i have stated that it works if i have it below where i state PU1S but anywhere else in the code it dosnt

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, but I just noticed your `stop` lines. Did you mean to run `___Sound.stop()` to stop playback and free a channel?

Comment: yes, but it should not matter as it is still only using 6 channels not 8, and the code works if i put it somewhere else in the code, but that would mean that the sound plays earlier then i want, if i put the code at the very start of def VideoD(): then it works but it wont work anywhere else, even if i make a new def.

Comment: Fix all such typos in the post, run the fixed code, see how the errors may change, and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: hopefully that should be better.